# GNURadio: file not received when repeat option is set to 'No'

Tags: gnuradio-companion

I've built a simple GNURadio project where I am trying to send a simple text file (called txF.txt) containing the sentence "Hello everyone!". The following are the blocks I've used:

File Source -> Packet Encoder -> GMSK Mod -> Throuttle -> GMSK Demod -> Packet Decoder -> File Sink

Block Settings is as follows:

1. File Source: txF.txt, Repeat = Yes
2. Packet Encoder: Sample/Symbols = 1, Bits/Symbol = 1
3. GMSK Mod: Sample/Symbol = 4
4. File Sink: rxF.txt, Unbuffered = On

When I set the repeat option in the source file to 'Yes', I get "Hello everyone!" repeated many times in the received file, rxF.txt. However, when I set the repeat option in the source file to 'No', the received file, 'rxF.txt', is created but it contains nothing in it (no matter the amount of time I wait before I stop the project).

When I replace the text file in the source and sink blocks with a .png photo, and set the repeat option to 'No', I only receive part of the source photo (usually more than three quarters of the photo), while the rest of the photo never gets received (no matter how long I wait).

1. Why is this happening?
2. Is there a way to send any file (text or photo) once without the need to keep repeat sending it, i.e., set the repeat option to 'No' and yet receive the source file once?
3. Also, is there a way to stop the project when the source file is completely received?